# Почему в С++ const не static?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
  const int a = 10; 
};

int main()
{
    S s1;
    S s2;
    std::cout<<&s1.a<<'\n';
    std::cout<<&s2.a<<'\n';
}
```

> output:
>   0x7787a69678f0
>
> 0x7787a6967900

Comment: Потому что `static` пропущен...

Comment: Не забывайте отмечать наиболее полезные ответы галочкой!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимость константного нестатического обьекта заключается не в том, что так решили авторы языка, а авторы языка  создали возможность иметь константный обьект в локальной области памяти или в статической области. В первом случаи время жизни обьекта заканчивается при выходе из области, а втором - обьект живет до конца программы.  И когда вы выбираете между статическим и нестатическим обьектом, должны учитывать именно этот факт.  Например, если немного изменить вашу структуру, то сразу прояснится разница:

```
struct S
{
  static const int sa = 10;
  const int a = 10;
  S(int n = 10) : a(n) {}
  void print() const { 
      cout << "non static member: " << a << endl
           << "static member" << sa << endl << endl; 
  }
};
```

Нестатическую константу вы можете инициализировать инициализатором конструктора, а статическая константа не принадлежит обьекту, она принадлежит статической области памяти, и для всех обьектов этот обьект единственный и имеет одно и то же значение:

```
S s1, s2(2), s3(3);
s1.print(); // a == 10, sa == 10
s2.print(); //a == 2,   sa == 10
s3.print(); //a == 3,   sa == 10
```

Можно привести еще много примеров, где правильно или лучше использовать нестатическую константу или наоборот, но я надеюсь и этот пример достаточен, чтобы понять почему константа не статическая(если конечно не обьялен как статическая)

Answer (score 6):

Потому что значения `const` полей можно устанавливать в конструкторе (в списке инициализации членов), так что у разных объектов они могут быть разные.

```
struct S
{
    const int a; 
    S(int value) : a(value) {}
};

int main()
{
    S s1(1);
    S s2(2);
    std::cout << s1.a << '\n'; // 1
    std::cout << s2.a << '\n'; // 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что у тебя в стеке создались две структуры и каждая из них имеет свою константу

Comment: bob torus как раз и спрашивает, почему у него в стеке каждая структура имеет свою константу

Comment: Вы ответили: потому что она не статична

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что так решили авторы языка.

C++ - это не тот язык, в котором компилятор будет додумывать, что же хотел сказать программист? Тут все проще: сказано - сделано (если сказанное явно не запрещено в стандарте).

Хочешь не статический член-константу - получи. Кто тебя знает, зачем это тебе? Вдруг действительно надо.

А хочешь статический - опиши явно.